# SFML: Projectile stops

Tags: c++, sfml, projectile

I am very new to SFML and C++. My problem is that I successfully fire projectiles towards the mouse. However as I move the mouse the projectiles also move.

EDIT:

Okay I solved my previous problem. However the projectile stops while it reaches the mouse position. How can the bullets continue to go further than its destination?

Code:

```
    if (isFiring == true) {

        sf::Vector2f startPos = sf::Vector2f(myPipe.getX(), myPipe.getY());
        sf::Vector2i mousePos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
        sf::Vector2f endPos = sf::Vector2f(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);

        double projSpeed{0.3};
        //float projSpeed = projSpeed * (myPipe.getY() - mousePos.y) / 100;
        Projectile newProjectile(20, startPos, endPos, projSpeed);
        projVec.push_back(newProjectile);
        isFiring = false;
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < projVec.size(); i++) {

        projVec[i].fire(delta.asMilliseconds());
        projVec[i].draw(window);
        clock.restart();

    }
```

fire function:

```
   void fire( float delta) {
    sf::Vector2f pos = projectile.getPosition();
    float veloX = (_end.x - pos.x);
    float veloY = (_end.y - pos.y);
    float distance = sqrt((veloX*veloX + veloY * veloY));

    float dx = veloX / distance;
    float dy = veloY / distance;
    projectile.move(dx * delta, dy * delta);
}
```

One more question, am I doing it correct with multiplying with delta? The bullets are really laggy and weird.

Comment: As an aside, you could write `for(auto proj : projVec)` instead of `for(int i = 0...`etc and then use `proj` instead of `projVec[i]`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried doing that right now but all that happend was that the projectile got stuck in the beginning. Super weird! :S

Comment: Your firing code has drawing code. That's not good. Keep concerns separate. Where do you move the projectiles once fired? Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1):

**(Original reply:)**

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll have to put it here...

So if I understand correctly you're saying you want to shoot the projectiles towards the mouse's position but don't want them to follow its position once fired? In this case:

I see you have the code to draw the projectiles inside that for-loop, which leads me to believe you are calling the loop continuously. But the same loop also contains the code used to shoot the projectiles, which means that you are also continuously calling this "fire" code. So you are steering the projectiles towards the current mouse position in every loop iteration which means they will always follow the current mouse position.

What you should be doing is move the code to shoot the projectiles and only call it once (you can only shoot a projectile once, right?) so a projectile's directional vector is not constantly altered, resulting in the problem you stated.

And make sure to always separate logic and rendering. Ideally you should be updating the physics (for example the projectile updating) at a fixed interval so that the game will run the same on all machines, and draw all your stuff separately.

If you do want the projectiles to always follow the mouse, you can use this (semi pseudo) code (I'm using this code in one of my games):

```
sf::Vector2f normalizedVector = normalize(mousePos - projectilePos);
normalizedVector.x *= speed * deltaTime;
normalizedVector.y *= speed * deltaTime;

projectile.move(normalizedVector);
```

---

**(Edit:)**

I made a quick example project that works. This doesn't use all of your code but hopefully gives you an idea how it can be done.

Here's a short video that shows what the code below does: https://webmshare.com/play/jQqvd

main.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "projectile.h"

int main() {
  const sf::FloatRect viewRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 800.0f, 600.0f);

  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(viewRect.width, viewRect.height), "Test");
  window.setFramerateLimit(120);
  window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(false);
  window.setKeyRepeatEnabled(false);

  sf::Clock deltaClock;
  const sf::Time timePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.0f / 60.0f);
  sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;

  std::vector<Projectile> projectiles;

  while (window.isOpen()) {

    timeSinceLastUpdate += deltaClock.restart();

    // process events
    {
      sf::Event evt;
      while (window.pollEvent(evt)) {
        switch (evt.type) {
          case sf::Event::Closed: { window.close(); } break;
          // shoot with left mouse button
          case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed: { switch (evt.mouseButton.button) { case sf::Mouse::Button::Left:  { 
            const sf::Vector2f center(viewRect.left + viewRect.width / 2, viewRect.top + viewRect.height / 2);
            const sf::Vector2f mousePos(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window)));
            const float angle = atan2(mousePos.y - center.y, mousePos.x - center.x);
            projectiles.push_back(Projectile(center, angle));
          } break; default: {} break; } } break;
          default: {} break;
        }
      }
    }

    // update
    {
      while (timeSinceLastUpdate > timePerFrame) {
        timeSinceLastUpdate -= timePerFrame;
        // update projectiles
        {
          for (std::size_t i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); ++i) {
            Projectile &proj = projectiles[i];
            proj.update(timePerFrame);
            if (!viewRect.intersects(proj.getBoundingBox())) { proj.destroy(); }
          }
          projectiles.erase(std::remove_if(projectiles.begin(), projectiles.end(), [](Projectile const &p) { return p.getCanBeRemoved(); }), projectiles.end());
        }
      }
    }

    // render
    {
      window.clear();
      for (std::size_t i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); ++i) {
        window.draw(projectiles[i]);
      }
      window.display();
    }

  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

projectile.h:

```
#ifndef PROJECTILE_H_INCLUDED
#define PROJECTILE_H_INCLUDED

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Projectile : public sf::Drawable {
 public:
  Projectile();
  Projectile(const sf::Vector2f pos, const float angle);
  virtual ~Projectile();

  const bool &getCanBeRemoved() const;
  const sf::FloatRect &getBoundingBox() const;

  void destroy();
  void update(const sf::Time dt);

 private:
  virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &renderTarget, sf::RenderStates renderStates) const;

  bool canBeRemoved_;
  sf::FloatRect boundingBox_;
  float angle_;
  float speed_;

  sf::RectangleShape shape_;

};

#endif
```

projectile.cpp:

```
#include "projectile.h"

Projectile::Projectile() :
  canBeRemoved_(true),
  boundingBox_(sf::FloatRect()),
  angle_(0.0f),
  speed_(0.0f)
{
}

Projectile::Projectile(const sf::Vector2f pos, const float angle) {
  canBeRemoved_ = false;
  boundingBox_ = sf::FloatRect(pos, sf::Vector2f(10.0f, 10.0f));
  angle_ = angle;
  speed_ = 0.5f;

  shape_.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(boundingBox_.left, boundingBox_.top));
  shape_.setSize(sf::Vector2f(boundingBox_.width, boundingBox_.height));
  shape_.setFillColor(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
}

Projectile::~Projectile() {
}

const bool &Projectile::getCanBeRemoved() const {
  return canBeRemoved_;
}

const sf::FloatRect &Projectile::getBoundingBox() const {
  return boundingBox_;
}

void Projectile::destroy() {
  canBeRemoved_ = true;
}

void Projectile::update(const sf::Time dt) {
  boundingBox_.left += static_cast<float>(std::cos(angle_) * speed_ * dt.asMilliseconds());
  boundingBox_.top += static_cast<float>(std::sin(angle_) * speed_ * dt.asMilliseconds());
  shape_.setPosition(boundingBox_.left, boundingBox_.top);
}

void Projectile::draw(sf::RenderTarget &renderTarget, sf::RenderStates renderStates) const {
  renderTarget.draw(shape_);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to make a projectile go towards the mouse direction but not follow the mouse once fired. I also believed there was some kind of update failure before. Hopefully now my code is a bit more structured.

Comment: Ty! I have reviewed your code quite briefly. First question that comes to mind, how do you make the project go further than the mouse?

Comment: @sockevalley It's already in the code. I just give it an angle at which it travels (the vector directing at the mouse position) and move the projectile at that angle, and it never stops and the angle (or: directional vector) is never altered after the projectile is shot. There is no final destination. It continuously travels at the given angle. In my example code, however, I remove any projectile that's out of view (see `Projectile::destroy()` and the `erase` below the game loop that removes all projectiles whose `canBeRemoved_` flag is set to true). That's the only constraint.